# Probably, bug in summation?

Tags: summation

We have:

```
Sum[Exp[s x], {x, 0, Infinity}, Regularization -> "Borel"] /. s -> 1 // N
Sum[Exp[s x], {x, 1, Infinity}, Regularization -> "Borel"] /. s -> 1 // N
- 1/2 f[0] + I Integrate[(f[I t] - f[(-I) t])/(E^(2 Pi t) - 1), {t, 0, Infinity}] // N
```

The output:

```
-0.581977
-1.58198
-0.581977
```

The last formula, [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_summation), is the sum starting with 1. But here we have it equal to the sum starting with 0.

Comment: If you are wanting to report a bug and don't have a question to ask, please file a report with Wolfram, Inc.:  https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190/how-to-report-bugs#:~:text=If%20you%20know%20that%20it,around%20bugs%20are%20welcome%20though.

Comment: @JimB I do not know if it is a bug or a mistake in Wikipedia

Answer (score 4):

In view of

```
Sum[Exp[s x], {x, 0, Infinity}, Regularization -> "Borel", GenerateConditions -> True]
```

$$ \text{ConditionalExpression}\left[-\frac{1}{e^s-1},e^{\Re(s)}<1\right]$$
and

```
Sum[Exp[s x], {x, 1, Infinity}, Regularization -> "Borel",GenerateConditions -> True]
```

$$\text{ConditionalExpression}\left[-\frac{e^s}{e^s-1},e^{\Re(s)}<1\right] $$

you incorrectly applied the formulas for $s=1$ since $\exp(1)>1$. This is a mistake of you.

Comment: Another formula gives the same result: Sum[((-Derivative[n - 1][f][0])*BernoulliB[n, 0])/n!, {n, 0, 100}] And it is also supposed to be from zero

Comment: @Anixx: Sorry, don't understand you. Can you kindly elaborate your comment? I will be waiting for a serious reply of you.